# C# GDI+ ScaleTransform ok on picturebox but image saved is original

Tags: c#, matrix, 2d, scaling, scaletransform

Hi I have the issue that when I use ScaleTransform(zoomFactor,zoomFactor) the image saved on disk is the original version always, while on screen in the picturebox the image is distorted in proportion to the zoomFactor.
Why this could be happening ? Shouldn't I have the final result as applied from e.Graphics on disk written image ?

My code is the following which is a version with matrix. but the instead of matrix I have used the ScaleTransform as well. Result is always the same:

```
                g=e.Graphics;//inside picturebox_paint()
                g.ScaleTransform(ratio * zoomFac, ratio * zoomFac);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage((Bitmap)bmp, 0, 0);
                int seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
                String destinationFile = @"C:\tmp\photoid\" + new Random(seed).Next() + "_conv.jpg";
//Here I get always the original image back!!!!
                bmp.Save(destinationFile);
```

I have used as well the following idiom but with same results:

```
            //Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            //matrix.Scale(zoomFac, zoomFac);
            //e.Graphics.Transform = matrix;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `PictureBox` draw the things it shows on screen into a **new** Bitmap, which you then can save!

As it is the `Image` will be saved in the original form and nothing you did in the `Paint` event, which actually painst onto the surface of the `PictureBox` will be saved.

So to save everything, i.e. The `Image`, possibly a `BackgroundImage` and all you draw in the `Paint` event you would call `DrawToBitmap` somehwere.

**Somewhere** means somewhere **else**, not in the `Paint` event, as it will call the `Paint` event to create the new `Bitmap`, causing an endless loop..

To call it you would do something like this:

```
Bitmap bmpSave = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmpSave, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
```

But maybe this is not really what you want? Maybe you actually want to modify the `Image`? In that case do **not** use the `Paint` event at all!

Instead do something like this:

```
Bitmap bmpSave = new Bitmap(yourNewWidth, yourNewHeight);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpSave))
{
    g.ScaleTransform(ratio * zoomFac, ratio * zoomFac);
    g.DrawImage((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image, 0, 0);  // 
    pictureBox1.Image = bmpSave;
    bmpSave.Save(...);
}
```

You could call this from somewhere where the scaling is being triggered from.

Note that doing the scaling repeatedly and each time from the previoulsy scaled version will **degrade the quality** rather fast. For this always scale from a saved version of the original!!

Btw: Using a `Matrix` for scaling doesn't really make a difference over `ScaleTransform`.

But if you want to do a direct scaling why not use the `DrawImage` overload which takes **two** `Rectangles`? This is the most common solution if all you want to to scale and maybe draw other stuff additionally..:

```
int newWidth = 100; int newHeight = 100; string yourFileName = "D:\\xyz123.jpg";

Bitmap bmpSave = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
Rectangle oldRectangle = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, pictureBox1.Image.Size);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpSave))
{
    g.DrawImage((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image, newRectangle, oldRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    bmpSave.Save(yourFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

And there there is the scaling `Bitmap` **constructor**:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, newWidth, newHeight);
```

Which I would recommend if all you want is to scale the `Image`. As the other solutions it will not change the `Image` displayed until you assign it back into the `PictureBox`..:

```
pictureBox1.Image = bmp ;
```

Don't forget to dispose of the old Image..

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, am I right to say if I use that bmpSave, it will save the distorted image but as well an area around image up to the boundaries of picturebox ? ( picturebox is 640x480), image is less. the aim is to save only the distorted image , am I right?

Comment: Yes, in that case don'r use the old size of the PictureBox for the new Bitmap!

Comment: Dear Taw yes the second snippet you gave is closer to what I want. The thing how could I recalculate the size of the new bitmap ? Since the scaletransform comes after the creation of bmpsave. 
You create a bmpSave with "newwidth", but in fact I don't know the newwidth until I call scaletransform. Right?

Comment: Look at the fourth snippet; it is the most direct way to save a scaled image.

Comment: As for calculating the new size: No, you already know the zoom factor, don't you? You can simply multiply it into the old size: `newWidth = (int)(oldWidth * zoomX / 100f);` etc.. if your zoom goes as percentages.. - Btw: It may help if you tell me more about the final purpose of the whole code and how the user is supposed to use it..!

Comment: Despite that there is the suggestion not writing a comment saying thanks, truly you helped me. I didn't realize that I had to do that. And in fact I don't understand why GRaphics on paint event is working like that, and while I apply transformation on this, the returned object is always the original. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The basic working of the `Graphics` object is that is only draws onto the `Bitmap` that is is related to. That is the Control's surface if the `Graphics` is from the `control.Paint` event or the `Bitmap` if it was created from `Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)`. It returns nothing, it only paint pixels in the related `Bitmap`.

Comment: Your code only drew a scaled image onto the surface but didn't change a separate Bitmap. See [here for a discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337825/picturebox-paintevent-with-other-method/27341797?s=3|0.0380#27341797) of drawing __onto__ a Control or __into__ a Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I messed with GDI but I think you need to copy back to the Bitmap here.

```
g.DrawImage(bmp, scaledwidth, scaledheight);
```

Try something like that before bmp.Save

**Edit**
Apologies for not seeing that you were copying back to the bitmap. Perhaps the overload which specifies the output rectangle is what you need. Try a DrawImage overload which has the destination Rect. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx